# Rstudio will not write "UTF-8" encoding with emoji data all of a sudden

Tags: r, csv, utf-8, emoji

I am working on a project that uses text files with emojis and I started having issue with writing a dataframe of emojis to a csv file. I have working with these files for some time now and so far I've been able to save the text data  using write.csv(x, "filename") and viewing them with read.csv("filename", encoding = "UTF-8") without any problems. Yesterday, quite suddenly, that stopped working. All the files that I previously saved will still display emojis using the read.csv() function but I can not write and read any new files. For example, if I have:

```
x <- c("","","")
View(x)
write.csv(x, "testemoji.csv")
x2 <- read.csv("testemoji.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
View(x2)
```

x will be

[image: viewed as this]

while x2 will be

[image: viewed as this]

I am using R verion 3.6.3 and windows 10.

What I have tried so far:

```
write.csv(x, "filename", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

write.table(x, "filename", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

write.csv2(x, "filename", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
x2<- read.csv2("filename", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I've tried every option of "tools - global options - coding - saving - default text encoding"

I've also tried messing with the locale language on the computer and the beta-UTF-8 option

when I check the encoding with `Encoding(x$v1)` it returns "UTF-8", "UTF-8", "UTF-8" but when I check `Encoding(x2$x)` it returns "unknown", "unknown", "unknown".

trying to change the encoding with `Encoding(x2$x)<- "UTF-8"` does not change the outcome.

I have been working on this project for 3 months now with no issues. I can't understand why it would come on so suddenly. To my recollection, I have not changed any preferences or setting is R, Rstudion or my computer before this happened. The deadline for this project is coming up in a week and I am getting desperate for answers. If anyone could please help I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth switching to use the `readr` library to have better encoding support. This worked for me

```
readr::write_csv(data.frame(x),'testemoji.csv')
x2<- readr::read_csv("testemoji.csv")
View(x2)
```